# GWT create two Views used one Presenter

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwtp, gwt-platform

I want to create two views that will use one presenter is it possible? I know that i can use two presenters that use one view, but i'm looking for opportunity to have two equals views that used one presenter.

I want to have something like this

```
MyView1 extends BaseView implements SharedPresenter.MyView
MyView2 extends BaseView implements SharedPresenter.MyView
```

Comment: Do you mean the same presenter *instance*, or the same presenter *class*? (Both is possible, but the answer is very different for each case.)

Comment: This is a very strange requirement. If two views are "equal", why do you need more than one of them?

Comment: I understand that this is ve-e-ery weird, but customer want so. This views have differense in css style. i suggest to change styles using button but my suggestion hasn't any success, so i need to have presenter and two equals views. I think i do not understand what did you say about presenter instance and presenter class. I think better to have one instance of presenter in memory, and only to change views...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the requirement can be for 2 views for different user agent(Desktop/Mobile).

1.Yes you can have 2 views sharing same presenter.

2.You will just have to define Presenter outside of the views and use it in viewImpl.

**Example**

You have AppviewMobile,AppviewDesktop.
Both can have Presenter{public String sayHello()}.

1.viewMobileImpl,viewDesktopImpl use the same presenter.

2.Define Presenter outside of views,say you have AppMyPresenter.

3.AppActivity will implement AppMyPresenter.

So you have 2 views,1 presenter,1 Activity..

Comment: Sorry,  i do not understand what are you talking about. I use GWTP i try to make 2 views and only one presenter. But when i try to bind presenter on each views i recieve error message: "Duplicate bindings"

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

Answer (score 0):

I found a bookmarked [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/gwt-platform/tHlpTRlQGtk/7CO064bD8E4J) on that very topic for you - Philippe Beaudoin pretty much answers your question with "...I'm planning to support (B) [1 View --> 1 Presenter ] only..." but also suggests a way forward using `PresenterWidgets`.

Cheers,

Comment: As i understood from the topic it's a bad idea to use 
(c) 1 presenter <- many views
So i should create PresenterWidget and bind views on it...